# Parametric plot and points

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

How I can add points to curve that has been plotted as parametric plot?

I am working on the brachistochrone example and I want to plot part of the cycloid, direct line and some combinations of them into same image.

How I can do this?

Comment: Have you seen the options `Epilog` and `Prolog`?  You can also use `Show[]` to combine your plot with other `Graphics[]`.

Comment: Sorry no I haven't. I am very new with Mathematica. I will look into these.